# Quarkus native run exec user process caused: exec format error

Tags: aws-lambda, quarkus, graalvm-native-image

I started studying Quarkus.

https://quarkus.io/guides/amazon-lambda

There was a problem while I was handling the tutorial on the site above.

If make a native work locally using AWS SAM or AWS Lambda the same error occurs during invoke.
(If it is not native, it works normally.)

MacBook M1 is in use, both graalvm and Java are arm64.

**

***ahahah@bcd0745cd453 ahahaha % sh target/manage.sh native invoke***

**
Invoking function

++ aws lambda invoke response.txt --cli-binary-format raw-in-base64-out --function-name HoiriasNative --payload file://payload.json --log-type Tail --query LogResult --output text
++ base64 --decode
START RequestId: a97a6513-afbf-4925-a0f0-1acab8dec543 Version: $LATEST
RequestId: a97a6513-afbf-4925-a0f0-1acab8dec543

***Error: fork/exec /var/task/bootstrap: exec format error
Runtime.InvalidEntrypoint***

END RequestId: a97a6513-afbf-4925-a0f0-1acab8dec543

REPORT RequestId: a97a6513-afbf-4925-a0f0-1acab8dec543  Duration: 2.94 ms   Billed Duration: 3 ms   Memory Size: 256 MB Max Memory Used: 3 MB
{"errorMessage":"RequestId: a97a6513-afbf-4925-a0f0-1acab8dec543
Error: fork/exec /var/task/bootstrap: exec format error","errorType":"Runtime.InvalidEntrypoint"}%

It's my bash_profile.

GRAALVM_HOME=/Library/JAVA/JavaVirtualMachines/graalvm-ce-java17-22.3.0/Contents/Home
JAVA_HOME=/Library/JAVA/JavaVirtualMachines/graalvm-ce-java17-22.3.0/Contents/Home
PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME

export JAVA_HOME
export PATH=${GRAALVM_HOME}/bin:$PATH

When I uploaded the native to Lambda, it was distributed as x86 so could this be a problem?

What should I do?
please Help me.

I tried to build it in another way, and the image was created normally.

```
quarkus build --native --no-tests -Dquarkus.native.container-build=true
```

Answer (score 1):

I Tried this yesterday as well.
It's currently not possible to build native images on Mac M1 (arm64) to run on Amazon Lambda. Probably with some virtual machine it might be possible.

Even on linux x86_64 you should build with:

`quarkus build --native -Dquarkus.native.container-build=true` to maximize compatibility.

Comment: Thank you. It doesn't work on M1....